# Objective-C : expected ']' before ';' token

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Trying to follow some basic examples and getting stuck by this code that is EXACTLY like the example I am following:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Sample Text" forKey:kWordsOfWisdom];
```

gives me the error:

```
expected ']' before ';' token
```

Comment: possibly have a unmatched [ before this line

Comment: is `kWordsOfWisdom` properly defined?

Comment: I had #define kWordsOfWisdom @"Sample Text";  - that ; on the end was the problem - thanks!

Comment: Somebody put this in an answer so I can up-vote it :-)

Comment: should post it as an answer, he figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this:

```
#define kWordsOfWisdom @"Sample Text";
```

that ; on the end was the problem.